# What are the downsides of using plasterboard for a (short) HVAC duct?

Tags: hvac

I need to run a 2 foot extension from a metal HVAC duct. The extension will go through a wall.  What are the downsides of framing this extension with plasterboard rather than sheet metal?

Comment: Supply or return?

Comment: @isherwood  Supply. Why does that matter?

Comment: Because returns are commonly built using stud bays as ducts. Supplies typically require full metal lining.

Comment: @isherwood  Would that warm (moist) air blowing on that paper-faced wallboard cause mold?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to put a piece of ductwork in than the drywall.  You can always use flexible duct work.